# Connecting to SQLite Database on Azure File Storage

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, azure-files

Problem: 
I cannot figure out what connection string to use to connect a WPF desktop application to a SQLite database on Azure File Storage. Thanks to the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) I am able to access the CloudFile from the app (so I have access to the URI), but when I pass the URI to a connection string to create a connection and then try to open the connection, I get an error message that my URI is invalid. The connection works fine when I try to connect to a SQLite database on my hard drive. Do I need to pass a key or something to the SQLite connection string to connect to a database on Azure File Storage? Is it even possible?

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Add all online (Azure file storage) data sources
    /// </summary>
    private void FindOnlineDataSources()
    {
        var accountName = "myAccountName";
        var keyValue = "myKeyValue";
        var useHttps = true;
        var exportSecrets = true;

        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, useHttps);
        var connString = storageAccount.ToString(exportSecrets);

        // Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to Azure Files.
        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

        // Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("myShare");

        // Ensure that the share exists.
        if (share.Exists())
        {
            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

            // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
            CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("myDirectory");

            // Ensure that the directory exists.
            if (sampleDir.Exists())
            {
                // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                var fileList = sampleDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                foreach (var fileTemp in fileList)
                {
                    if (fileTemp is CloudFile && TestConnection(SQLiteOnlineConnectionBuilder(fileTemp.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.AbsoluteUri)))
                    {
                        // Store reference to data source
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Test data source connection to determine if it is accessible
    /// </summary>
    private bool TestConnection(DbConnection connection)
    {
        bool retval = false;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
            retval = true;
        }
        catch { }

        return retval;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Create SQLite connection from URI string
    /// </summary>
    private DbConnection SQLiteOnlineConnectionBuilder(string uri)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Uri = uri,
                ForeignKeys = true,
                BinaryGUID = false,

            }.ConnectionString
        };
    }
```

Background:
I am building a desktop app for use within my company. The data for the app is held in a SQLite database. We will only have a maximum of 5 users accessing the data at one time so I decided it would be unnecessary to try to set up a full server - SQLite seems like a great option.

However, I am trying to put the SQLite database into our Azure File Storage account so that multiple users can access it thru the desktop app wherever they have internet access. We don't have a central company network so I figured Azure File Storage would be the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the Azure File share? SQLite expects a file path, and knows nothing of the Azure Files SDK/API, and it won't work with an internal reference to a given folder given to you by the SDK.

Comment: Yeah I tried mounting the file share yesterday but unfortunately my ISP blocks port 445.

Comment: @cjohnson221 did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Tronald Unfortunately not. I've made do with having one person write to the SQLite database at a time using Dropbox, but I'll have to find a different solution if our employee user base grows.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so one option with Azure File Share that is not very secure but might suit your needs is to map the azure file share to where the desktop app resides. Then you can just point to the sqlite *db file inside the mapped drive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows - how to make the mapping.